# Implementing GJK algorithm with SymPy

Tags: sympy

I am trying to implement GJK alg, entirely in symbolic form with Sympy,
but I am not sure it is possible/computationally feasible.

Did anyone tried this?

Comment: I tried the sweep-line method and recall that it was painfully slow.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "symbolic form" but with symbols the algorithm would fail as soon as it encounters a conditional like `if a < 2`.

Comment: Exactly, this is why I was using Piecewise, but in this way the algorithm becomes soon impracticable